# How do I code a Mono Daemon

Tags: c#, linux, mono, daemon, mono-service

I'm trying to write a Mono C# daemon for linux.

I'd like to do a starts and stops of it when its done processing instead of just killing the process.

Does anyone have any examples of this?

Edit: I figured out how to use start-stop-daemon --background in debian, so I think I'll just use that for now.

Edit: I'm implementing this in java as well and they have this nice addShutdownHook that catches terminating the app. I need to spend a little more time sorting out the dependencies for mono service, or find a way to catch app termination.

There is the SessionEnd event, but thats only available for services and not console apps

**Answer:**
[using mono-service to wrap a windows service on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351971/using-mono-service-to-wrap-a-windows-service-on-linux)

Comment: I too would really love to see what the answer is to this one, I searched unsuccessfully a few months ago.

Comment: mono-service use old garbade collector whis is leaks in my 2.10 on debian. So I use cron in conjunction with mono-sgen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should implement a service and use mono-service. Google for it and you'll find several examples.

Comment: If the examples are easy to find, kindly link them here. A reference to Google is rather unstable over time.

Comment: I found it easier to write a console application since it is then trivial to run the application in background in Linux - which makes it a "daemon".

Comment: But how does this work if you've `mkbundle`'d your Mono application?

Comment: Just for posterity. Here is how you can use POSIX (unix style service ) https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Run-ServiceStack-as-a-daemon-on-Linux And here is how you build a windows type service running on Unix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359190/c-sharp-service-as-a-daemon-in-debian-with-mono-service/15361225

Comment: I implemented Windows service application and I running on Ubuntu with mono-service. When I rebooted system my application stopped and I need to start mono-service again. Is it some common issue? Does somebody encountered with this?

Answer (score 25):

To receive notifications in the Unix way, that is using signals, you want to use the [Mono.Unix.UnixSignal](http://mapsbkp.geolives.com/monodoc/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aMono.Unix.UnixSignal) for each signal that you plan on receiving and then call UnixSignal.WaitAny () on an array of signals.

---

You would typically do this on a separate thread.

Answer (score 16):

A simple method would be to listen on a (local, high) port and receive commands from a management client, like bind does.

A more unix-ish way would be to [register a signal handler](http://www.jprl.com/Blog/archive/development/mono/2008/Feb-08.html) using [UnixSignal](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AMono.Unix.UnixSignal) and shutdown properly on receiving a certain signal. See the [Mono FAQ, "Can I use signal handlers with Mono?"](http://www.mono-project.com/FAQ:_Technical) for caveats and an example.

[lupus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/27051/lupus) has found [mono-service](http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=man%3Amono-service(1)), which is a hosting process using the [`ServiceProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.aspx) interfaces. Sadly this requires setting `MONO_DISABLE_SHM`, which disables some features in Mono, in particular cross-process IPC systems.

Comment: I should be ok with the lack of IPC

Answer (score 4):

A daemon under Linux typically listens to signals, like the kill signal, but there are others that allow it to do things like a soft restart (reads back in configuration), and so forth.

Typically this is accompanied by a script in the /etc/init.d directory that controls starting and stopping such daemons. Typically a pid file is created under /var/run, that keeps the process id for the script to identify the process quickly.

Even when coding for Mono, you'd do well understanding the environment for which you're coding, since there's no difference between a Mono process or a native process (created in C, for example) or a script.

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Miguel de Icaza recently wrote about a new [Mono C# interactive shell](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) that you should be able to daemonize easily enough.  Miguel has a [follow-up article](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Sep-29.html) with some source code that shows how you can include the interactive shell in other C# applications.  It may serve as a good starting point for your daemon.

Note that the interactive shell requires Mono version 2.2, which hasn't been released yet. The code is available in [Mono's svn repository](http://www.mono-project.com/SVN), however.

Comment: interesting way to do it, I'm putting this into production so I'm using only released versions of mono.

Answer (score 0):

David is correct, stopping a service is accomplished via a UNIX signal, and you should use a signal handler to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, I use a shell script.  It starts my mono app, and then when my app quits (intentionally or unintentionally), looks at any return signals which my app has set.  This can be used to instruct the script to copy in an update, restart or quit.  If my app crashes, no signal is returned, so the script will restart my app and send me an e-mail with that last few lines of the console output.

See [Windows like services development in LINUX using MONO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221110/windows-like-services-development-in-linux-using-mono/1234761#1234761)