# using mono-service to wrap a windows service on linux

Tags: linux, mono, mono-service

Hi I'm trying to use mono-service2 to run a stock Windows Service Project from visual studio. I'm running this on debian with mono 2.0 and compiling with.

```
gmcs *.cs -pkg:dotnet
```

I try and start with this (I've tried with -d set to the dir with the app and -n,-m set)

```
mono-service2 -l:service.lock --debug Program.exe
```

The only code change is to add writelines for testing

**Service1.cs**

```
using System;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace spikes
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("starting...");
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("stopping....");
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting is this error

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall ---> System.DllNotFoundException: libMonoPosixHelper.so
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall:_L_ctermid ()
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall..cctor () [0x00000]
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoServiceRunner.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]
```

Thanks for your help

**Answer**

I was missing the LD____LIBRARY____PATH env variable, so I added it in a csh for a test

```
#!/bin/csh
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .:/usr/local/lib
mono-service2 -l:service.lock --debug Program.exe
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Where is your LD_LIBRARY_PATH pointing to? Is `libMonoPosixHelper.so` in there?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have *libmono0* installed.