# Linux Mono Equivalent of .NET Windows Service

Tags: .net, linux, windows-services, mono

I have a .NET Windows service that I would like to port to Mono on Linux.

What would be the proper way to install the service on Linux so that it works like a Windows service (i.e. autostart, runs when no users are logged in, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637948/how-to-migrate-a-net-windows-service-application-to-linux-using-mono).

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to register your software as a *daemon* by writing a script to go into [init.d](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/).