# mono-service on windows

Tags: windows, mono, mono-service

I have inherited an application that uses mono that runs a windows service. All of the original developers are gone.  The production version uses mono on linux. I am trying to get a development environment up and running. I decided to use windows as the base platform running mono up top of it. Ok maybe not the best idea given my current issue but I would like to try to understand the issue before moving the environment to linux.

The issue is I can’t get mono-service to run. I can get small winforms apps to run using mono. My issue is the same as a previous question with an answer. [using mono-service to wrap a windows service on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351971/using-mono-service-to-wrap-a-windows-service-on-linux)
However I can’t translate the answer on what to do in a windows environment. I am sure I am having an issue with not loading a dll.

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown
 by the type initializer for Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall ---> System.EntryPointNotF
oundException: Mono_Posix_Syscall_L_ctermid
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall:_L_ctermid ()
  at Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall..cctor () [0x00000]
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at MonoServiceRunner.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000]

I have added the monodevelop environment variables  and set to “all” and have a log file. No text is going to log file. And I can’t get anymore info that what is posted above. Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

I think mono-service only runs on Linux.  On Windows, you can just do what you would normally do to install/run a .Net service using ServiceBase.  The point of mono-service is to emulate the Windows behavior on Linux.

Comment: This is correct, Mono.Unix.Native.Syscall is not available on Windows, obviously.