# How to start a service in C# on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I would like to start a service on my Linux server using a C# console application, through Mono.

```
public static void StartService(string serviceName, int timeoutMilliseconds)
{
  ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
  try
  {
    TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeoutMilliseconds);

    service.Start();
    service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running, timeout);
  }
  catch
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Would this work?

As an alternative, is there a way to send a command to Linux through C# like you can send it on Windows systems?

I'm trying to start a Linux service using a C# Executable.

Comment: http://mattdeboard.net/2012/10/19/how-to-run-windows-service-as-linux-daemon/ and http://linux.die.net/man/1/mono-service

Comment: possible duplicate of [using mono-service to wrap a windows service on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351971/using-mono-service-to-wrap-a-windows-service-on-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a command by doing this;

```
Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "/bin/bash";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = "-c 'your command here'";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.Start();
```