# C#/Mono Run Server in Background

Tags: c#, .net, mono, background-process

I created a Server that listens for HTTP connections all the time. It's a default Console Application and runs on a Linux Machine using Mono (2.4).

The Problem is that i want this Server to move itself to the background (deamonize itself).
I couldn't find a Solution on Google and `mono Server.exe &` is not really what i'm looking for (the effect is the correct, i just want the program to do it itself), eventhough it works for the moment.

Any hints/ideas?

Comment: This question is a duplicate.  It's been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186493/how-do-i-code-a-mono-daemon The answer is to use mono-service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using mono-service now.

Answer (score 2):

Well about the best it can do is span another copy of itself with system.diagnositics.process.

If you're willing to be *nix specific you can P/Invoke daemonize(), which is: fork(), and parent calls _exit while child calls setpgrp(0).

Comment: Thanks, this should work, eventhough it feels a little clumsy. I'll try it but i hope someone else knows something simpler and more straight forward.