# Using System.Diagnostics.EventLog in a C# daemon and mono-service

Tags: linux, logging, mono, mono-service

I've just managed to implement my first daemon using C# and mono (hurrah). It's working all fine except one thing. In windows for a service to log into system's log base, one should use `System.Diagnostics.EventLog` class. This class comes with a method named `WriteEntry` to log a string into system logs. The same class exists in mono and compiles just fine but it seems it does nothing. Or perhaps I don't know where to look. Where does the logs generated this way go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not 100% clear from your question - are you expecting the event log code to be working on Linux?

If so, perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15361225/233944) will help you.